# Pass data and receive on textfield widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

How to pass a data from first screen to second screen but should receive on `textfield` widget in second screen. I have tried but there is no option in `textfield` widget, how to do this?

```
TextField(
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    fillColor: Colors.white,
                                    hintText: "",
                                    filled: true,
                                    labelText: "First name",
                                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.white),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                    ),
                                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.white),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                                    )),
                              ),
```

Comment: Are you able to send and receive data?

Comment: @Diwyansh Yes, but how i receive data in textfield widget ?

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set `default` text in your **TextField** you need to use **TextEditingController**, you can use it by `initializing` in **initState** or directly to the **TextField**, here are the examples

To `initialize` with **initState**

```
  late TextEditingController _controller;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller.text = widget.text;
    super.initState();
  }
```

To pass value `directly`

```
TextField(
            controller: TextEditingController(text: widget.text),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                hintText: "",
                filled: true,
                labelText: "First name",
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                )),
          )
```

Comment: What if i type on textfield widget does pass data will change ?

Comment: you need to refresh the state and the variable's value by calling setState or using any state management tool like Bloc, Provider etc.